# How to Remove the Quick Launch Column in a Publishing Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, publishing-site, quick-launch

Hello felas and ladies,

I need to remove the quick launch column in a document library, while using the Modern View of Sharepoint.

I need to keep activated the Sharepoint Publishing infrastructure, so I need a hack to can remove the quick launch by using powershell or other settings.
I know that performing this task is possible, because I did it in past BUT I do not remember how to do it again!
[image: uic]
I would appreciate your answers-

Answer (score 2):

We can create a custom CSS style and inject the CSS on modern pages using SPFx extensions to achieve it.

The following solution with source code for your reference.

[SPFx Applications Customiser CSS Injection](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss)

To hide the Quick launch, we can use CSS code below:

```
ul.ms-Nav-navItems{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am gonna try this solution :)

Comment: The extension works but now I need to find the name of the element to delete the box that is circuled in orange in the picture. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you use .Files-leftNav { display:none; } to achieve your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

The solution of LZ_SFT was right.

The code to hide the Quick launch column (including his links and other elements) it is:

.Files-leftNav {
  display:none;
}

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if something changed since LZ_MSFT posted an answer but it didn't work for me.

What did work for me was:

```
<style type="text/css">  
   div[id^='spLeftNav'] {display: none !important;} 
</style>
```